# Sync iPad music

Tags: music, ipad, ios

I know that in older versions of iOS, users were able to sync their iDevice with ubuntu. As I'm writing this now, the latest version of iOS is 7.1.2, and most of the users are using it (and we're waiting iOS 8 release), and I'm trying to find a way to sync my iPad's music catalog in ubuntu.
This is my current situation:

- I have kubuntu 14.04
- I have an iPad mini with iOS 7.1.2
- I have `libimobiledevice` version `1.1.5+git20140313.bafe6a9e-0ubuntu1`
- when I connect my iPad to my computer, they recognize each other, and I can see photos on my device like a usual folder in dolphin (KDE file browser).
- and clearly, **I don't want to directly or inderictly use Windows or Mac OSX**. I want to do it in linux.

but I have no luck making Amarok (KDE music player) recognize the device, or do any other thing with the device.
Is there any way to do this?

Comment: @fergus-fettes says:"Banshee seems to have the best iPad support, it recognizes it and can delete songs. That is all atm as far as I can see."